How to reopen page instead of opening a second time
A user can click on push notification and open a target page like so:
if (data["myPage"] == 'Page1' || data["myPage"] == 'Page2') {
  navigatorKey.currentState?.push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => targetPage(
          page: data['myPage'],
          key1: data['value1'],
          key2: data['value2'],
        ),
      ));
}

How can I reopen/reload the same page if the user clicks on another notification that leads to targetPage?
With the code above, I just open a second instance of the same page.
Thank you!

interesting. For my app, i use go_router and use context.go() instead of context.push(). It would pop all the screen and go to exactly destination route without caring about reload things.

@Nguyenfamily That's actaully correct. You can see my answer below. You may use routeInformationParser.configuration.

You can use the go_router package.
Specifically, you can check if the routeInformationParser.configuration has your desired route on the stack. And if it already does, then, go to that route. Otherwise, push the new route onto the stack.
Create a function:
bool doesRouteExists(String route) {
  try {
    return goRouter.routeInformationParser.configuration
        .findMatch(route)
        .matches
        .isNotEmpty;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

and use it:
void handleNavigation(String data) {
  if (doesRouteExists('/target')) {
    print('Route exists');
    goRouter.goNamed('target', extra: data);
  } else {
    print('Route does not exist');
    goRouter.pushNamed('target', extra: data);
  }
}


Complete runnable example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final GoRouter goRouter = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => HomePage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/target',
      name: 'target',
      builder: (context, state) => MyTargetPage(data: state.extra as String?),
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: goRouter,
      );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home')),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Open Target Page'),
            onPressed: () => handleNavigation('Data 1'),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class MyTargetPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? data;
  MyTargetPage({this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Target Page')),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Data: $data'),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Update Data'),
                onPressed: () => handleNavigation('Updated Data'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}

void handleNavigation(String data) {
  if (doesRouteExists('/target')) {
    print('Route exists');
    goRouter.goNamed('target', extra: data);
  } else {
    print('Route does not exist');
    goRouter.pushNamed('target', extra: data);
  }
}

bool doesRouteExists(String route) {
  try {
    return goRouter.routeInformationParser.configuration
        .findMatch(route)
        .matches
        .isNotEmpty;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}


See also

flutter go_router: how to manually match active path / route?

[go_router] Check if route exists (Github) 


